# typescript auto imports not working macos

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, auto-import

I have a project and I am adding some typescript but typescript doesnt auto import. And i dont understand why. See below my file structure, tsconfig and an example:

**ts config**

```
{ 
    "compilerOptions": { 
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "allowUnusedLabels": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": false,
        "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
        "outDir": "../Js/",
        "baseUrl": "./",
    },
    "include":[ 
       "*.ts"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true
}
```

**file structure**
[image]

**App ts expected import suggestion**
[image]
Here I am expecting to see a suggestion for an import for `ImageRowsInitializer` from the file called `images-row.ts`.

**images-row.ts**

```
export class ImageRowsInitializer {
    
    private image_rows : ImagesRow[];
    
    constructor() {
        const htmlImageRows = document.getElementsByClassName("row-container");
        for (let i = 0; i < htmlImageRows.length; i++) {
            const imagerow = htmlImageRows[i];
            this.image_rows.push(new ImagesRow(imagerow as HTMLElement));
        }
    }
}
```

I dont get why i am not getting suggestions..
please let me know if more information is needed i am happy to supply :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Click on TypeScript version in the lower-right corner of VSCode.
[image]

Now from the command section, select workspace typescript version.

[image]

if the error is still not fixed, then  -
go to settings,
Search for "tsdk"
click on edit in settings.json
and delete the property     `"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules\\typescript\\lib"`

The Third Option is to include all the files under your "Typescript" folder.
In your case, typescript is unable to locate all the files in your project.
To locate all the files, modify your `include` array in tsconfig to `"include":[  "**/*" ]`. It will inform the TS compiler of VSCode to search all the ts files under "Typescript" folder.

This may fix your auto import issue.

[image]

Comment: for me the use workspace version doesnt exist. Could it be because i have typescript installed globally?

Comment: Yes. It may be the reason.
Try the second fix. 
go to settings => search for 'tsdk' => click on edit in settings.json => delete "typescript.tsdk" property.

Comment: Didnt fix it :(

Comment: I created a setup/folder-structure as you mentioned in your question. 
Then I delete  this from tsconfig.json - 
`"include":[ 
       "*.ts"
    ],`

and auto-import works for me.

Comment: awesome! that fixed it, any clue why this happens? I am a newb to typescript.

Comment: That `include` array informs typescript compiler that it has to look into those paths which are mentioned in `include` array. So, if you change your `include` array to `"include":[ 
       "**/*"
    ]` , it will include all the files where tsconfig is defined(in your case it will look for all the files under "Typescript" folder. just change the `include` to `"include":[ 
       "**/*"
    ]`

Comment: thanks for the explanation. If you add it to your answer i will accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

Select TypeScript Version to be your workspace version, not the vscode version solved the issue on my end. Not sure why though.

[image]