# Typescript autocomplete/autoimport not working in Angular project subfolders

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, auto-import

I have an Angular + NodeJS project with the follow structure:

```
/node_modules
/tsconfig.json
/tsconfig.app.json
/tsconfig.spec.json
/package.json
/src/
   client/
      main.ts
   server/
      node_modules
      tsconfig.json
      package.json
      app.ts
```

But **Autocomplete** / **Autoimport** is not working in any file under `server/` or any other subfolder created in the same folder than the Angular project.

How can I solve that?

---

I tried `include` the `server/` in the root `tsconfig.json` but nothing, also tried: [typescript auto imports not working macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62540283/typescript-auto-imports-not-working-macos) which is not related to Angular.

Answer (score 0):

The types ignored where in `server/node_modules` but fixed adding `"typeRoots": ["node_modules"]` in `server/tsconfig.json`.